# Show hidden secondary menu on mobile without setting primary menu to default expanded

Tags: html, css, wordpress, genesis

I am using the "[No Sidebar Pro](http://my.studiopress.com/themes/no-sidebar/#demo-full)" WordPress theme built on Genesis. By default, this theme hides the secondary/footer menu on mobile. StudioPress's support told me that removing the following from the CSS would allow the secondary menu to be visible on mobile.

```
.js nav {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

Indeed, this does show the secondary menu on mobile as desired, however now the primary menu defaults to being expanded on page load. When I kept the above code present as is, the primary menu would default to closed on page load.

How can I modify this CSS so that the footer menu shows on mobile, but the main menu defaults to closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing those styles, add the following right below that.

```
.js nav.nav-secondary {
    display: block;
}
```

This should fix your issue.